# How to parse a text file successfully in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails, and am trying to just set up a simple app that parses a list into a database that's displayed in the app.

The list I have is a text file of all the films John Williams scored, and the actual parsing goes fine, but when trying to put it into a database it hits an error. (NoMethodError).

Parser file:

```
RAILS_ENV = 'development'
require File.expand_path('../environment', __FILE__)

f = File.open("Films.txt")


f.each do |line|
    title = line[0,line.index('(')]
    year = line[line.index('('),line.rindex(')')]


  puts title
  puts year
  puts '/'


@Film = Film.new
@Film.title = title
@Film.year = year
@Film.save
end
f.close
```

It says the error is an undefined method "title=" and I'm not sure what it means.

This is completely for my own interest so feel free to link me good readings or whatever, but a solution would be nice too.

cheers.

Edit:

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141221022528) do

  create_table "films", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string "title"
    t.string "year"

  end

end
```

Model:

```
class Film < ActiveRecord::Base

    def index

      @Film = Film.all
      @Film.title 
      @Film.year

  end

end
```

films_controller.rb:

```
class FilmController < ApplicationController
    def index

      @films = Film.all
      @films.title 
      @films.year

  end

 def film_params
      params.require(:film).permit(:title, :year)
    end

   def new
    @films = Film.new
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you sure the code you've posted is correct? The equal sign (=) is a valid character for a method name in Ruby, so does your code really say @Film.title = title or does it say @Film.title= title (take note of the difference in whitespace in the two examples)?

Comment: Yeah, there definitely is the space there, which is why I'm confused, I think.

Comment: Then are you sure that you've got the error message correct? Edit your question with the first several lines of the trace. The interpreter may be encountering the error in some other part of your code. You may also want to do a "find in files" search from the root of your application directory for "title=" which would help to locate the issue.

Comment: http://imgur.com/0stXWvc

Is the response I get from command prompt when I try to run the parser. 1941 is the title of the first film in the list, (1979) is the year it was released, and the / breaks up each film. After that is, obviously, the error message. Thanks for your time man.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the stack trace, since outside resources can go dead (or in the case of imgur, can become unavailable due to relentless hammering by redditors). What I'm suspecting now is your Film.rb model. Does it really have a title field? You can post the model file, as well as the relevant bit of schema.rb where your films table is defined.

Comment: Edited with model and schema. Doing trace now.

Comment: Look at this controller code: `@Film = Film.all`. This should be `@films = Film.all`. The next line `@Film.title` is where the error comes from because you've effectively defined `@Film` as an ActiveRecordRelation (an array of AR objects), whereas the call to `@Film.title` is meant to refer to a single ActiveRecord object. Also, in Ruby/Rails, you want to name fields with a lowercase character to start. Reserve uppercase characters for classes and modules. After defining `@films` remove all other code and see what happens.

Comment: If I remove@Film.title and @Film.year, and just leave@films = Film.all



it still throws up the same error.

Comment: I missed something: that index method of yours belongs in a controller, not in your model. Do you have a films_controller.rb file in app/controllers? If you're not using a controller, you need one, and it has to have a film_params method that implements strong parameters (I'm assuming you're on Rails 4).

Comment: Edited to include films_controller.

Comment: Have you [run your migration(s) for the relevant Rails environments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#running-migrations-in-different-environments)?

Comment: I ran rake db:migrate, and it didn't display any errors just hung for a couple of seconds and then went back to normal command prompt with no output.

Comment: index method in controller has the same kind of problem I pointed out earlier. You can't say `@films.title` because you're referring to an ARRelation, not a single ActiveRecord. You need to create an each loop in your films.html.erb view that goes through `@films` and does film.title for each film in `@films`.

Comment: Re first comment: Yes, the equal sign (`=`) is a valid character for a method name in Ruby. But that's only half the truth, @MarsAtomic. It does not matter whether you write `@Film.title = title` (with space before the `=`) or `@Film.title= title` (without space before the `=`). In both cases, `=` would be interpreted as the assignment operator, thus both cases would try to assign the `title` object to the `title` attribute of the (unfortunately named) `@Film` instance variable.

Comment: To perform the assignment to an attribute (remember that Ruby does not have public instance variables), Ruby tries to call the assignment accessor method (a.k.a. the attribute writer). It tries so by following the naming convention `<attribute name>=`, thus tries to invoke the method `title=`. For ActiveRecord objects, these accessor methods should be provided dynamically based on the database schema, so I'm uncertain why the call fails here. (A stack trace would help, indeed.)

Comment: What's the best way to provide you helpful folks a stack trace?

Comment: Isn't one printed with the `undefined method "title="` message?

Comment: Is http://imgur.com/0stXWvc what you're looking for then? I'm aware I'm meant to put it into the question, and I will.